# How to run Windows executables from a cronjob via a shell (bash) script in WSL 2?

Tags: bash, shell, cron, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Windows 10 x64 with WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2).

In WSL2, I have cron running the following task:

```
* * * * * /mnt/c/Users/Colin/Desktop/test.sh
```

The contents of test.sh (currently executing every minute for test purposes) are as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32

taskkill.exe /im calibre.exe
sleep 5
<rsync command here>
echo "Done with rsync, launching calibre..."
screen -dm bash -c \"/mnt/c/Users/Colin/Desktop/startcalibre.sh\"
```

This script works perfectly when executed from the WSL2 prompt.

**However, cron will not run either the taskkill.exe command nor the screen command (which launches calibre) in the script.** I do see that cron executes the script because I see that rsync runs since I can see that in Wireshark. It seems that cron on WSL2 has problems with running Windows executables (taskkill.exe, etc) in particular (I can't even seem to get notepad.exe to launch via a cron-executed script).

What should I add to the script to get cron to execute Windows executables?

Comment: Where is `taskkill.exe`? Is it in the path that you've set? (Or, can you even directly run a windows exe from Bash in WSL?)

Comment: @miken32 Yes, that's one of the great things about WSL.  It uses Linux's binfmt_misc to register a handler for Windows PE executables.  It also automatically mounts Windows drives as `/mnt/<drive_letter>` and adds the Windows path to Linux/WSL path on startup.  So `/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/taskkill.exe` is executable from the normal shell in WSL.  However, `cron`'s path, of course is *very* limited.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds but `/mnt/c/Windows/system32` is being set in the PATH of the script.

Comment: I'd throw in some debugging to the script, e.g. `logger "$(which -a taskkill.exe)"` to make sure it's finding everything it should.

Comment: @miken32 Oh %*!# I missed that.  Interesting that I was able to reproduce the problem using that script though, so let me double-check it.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds case sensitivity?

Comment: @miken32 You'd think, but probably not.  Since Windows paths aren't case sensitive, the automount method (9P) doesn't utilize case by default.  It's possible to set case-sensitivity, but unlikely that it's been done.  Anyway, I just retested and I did *not* add the PATH line that the OP has.  When I do, `notepad.exe` (with no qualifying path) works correctly for me.  I guess I'm going to need to vote-to-reopen.  If you are willing to as well, then we just need one more.  **Completely my bad** on the early duplicate call :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245674/discussion-between-notthedr01ds-and-miken32).

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily an answer, but I'm hoping this will lead us to one ...

First, let's try a script that pretty much anyone with WSL can run to see if we can reproduce the problem in more of an MRE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32

echo $PATH > ~/cronlogger

notepad.exe &
sleep 2
which taskkill.exe >> ~/cronlogger

taskkill.exe /im notepad.exe >> ~/cronlogger 2>&1
```

I placed this script in my `%userprofile%/Desktop/test.sh` as well and set it to run with the same `crontab` line (via `sudo crontab -u ntd -e`):

```
* * * * * /mnt/c/Users/ntd/Desktop/test.sh
```

It works for me as expected -- Every minute, Notepad pops up and then after 2 seconds is killed.  The contents of `~/cronlogger` are:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32
/mnt/c/Windows/system32/taskkill.exe
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process "Notepad.exe" with PID 4268.
```

Of course, wait until a few seconds after the top of the minute to make sure you capture the whole thing.

I notice that you have the `..\System32` path twice, but that shouldn't matter.  Also, case-sensitivity isn't an issue unless you have specifically turned it on for Windows drives via `/etc/wsl.conf`.

I tested this:

- On Windows 10 21H2
- On Windows 11 using the latest Preview version of WSL
- As my normal user `sudo crontab -u ntd -e`
- As the root user `sudo crontab -e`

All worked okay for me.

At this point, the only thing I can think that might throw it off is if you were using a Systemd script of some sort.  I've seen Systemd throw off the WSL `binfmt_misc` registration so that WSL can no longer run Windows executables.  I could imagine this could happen inside the Cron daemon (but still be working via the default shell).

Comment: This sortof worked for me but not quite. The actual notepad window is not displayed, but notepad was run and showed u in task manager - it was just invisible. I'm running windows 10 22H2 build 19045.2965. Running the script straight from bash notepad was displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This may be relevant (but I'm not sure exactly what Calibre does) and it was the cause of the test from @NotTheDr01ds not working for me.

WSL crond is generally started by Windows Task Scheduler. If you select the option "Run whether user is logged on or not", then task scheduler will run crond as a background process which cannot generate interactive displays. In turn, this means that all processes started by cron will be background processes.

If the process you want to start with cron has any visible user interface then you need to select "Run only when user is logged on" in Task Scheduler for the task to start cron.